# Showing static table using UI5

Tags: sapui5

I want to show a table like below with fixed number or rows and columns using SAP UI5.

[image]

Is there any other way to show such? using default sap.ui.table.Table doesn't look proper.
I am new to UI5 so I have very little idea about it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`MatrixLayout`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#test-resources/sap/ui/commons/demokit/MatrixLayout.html) if you really have a fixed layout, or for some more flexibility, the [`RowRepeater`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#test-resources/sap/ui/commons/demokit/RowRepeater.html) control.

But just out of curiosity, why would the standard `sap.ui.table.Table` control not suffice?

Answer (score 0):

First make an object of which type you want to add in table.
Suppose you want an autocomplete an textField in the table so make an autocomplete and textField object as shown below

```
 var autocomplete1 = new sap.ui.commons.AutoComplete({
        editable : true,
        displaySecondaryValues: true,
        items    : {
            path: "/AutoComplete/AccountAssignment",
            template: new sap.ui.core.ListItem({text: "{key}", additionalText: "{desc}"})
            }
        });


var shortText = new sap.ui.commons.TextField({
        editable : true,
    });
```

and use it in a table as template of the column

```
    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
                            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "column1"}),
                            template: autocomplete1.clone(),
                            width: "30px"               
                        }));

    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "column2"}),
        template : shortText.clone(),
        width: "150px"
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Table>
    <columns>
        <Column>
            <Text text="A" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Text text="B" />
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Text text="A1" />
                <Text text="B1" />
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Text text="A2" />
                <Text text="B2" />
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For just a few datasets you should consider to use another control like a 'Form'. A table normally is good if there are a lot of datasets and you would like to filter, group etc. If there are a lots of datasets but no columns are needed it's recommended to use a 'List'.